# Extending components in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to extend a component in PrimeNg using Angular 2. I tried a simple example to extend the MultiSelect component and was unsuccessful. I am getting the below error "No provider for DomHandler!" in the browser console. Has anyone tried extending the PrimeNg components. Is it even possible.

The exact exception:<>
**"﻿EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0            caused by: No provider for DomHandler! 

ErrorHandler.handleError    @   error_handler.js:54 

(anonymous) @   application_ref.js:261 

ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:330 

    onInvoke    @   ng_zone.js:273 

    ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:329 

    Zone.run    @   zone.js:126 

    (anonymous) @   zone.js:679

    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:363 

    onInvokeTask    @   ng_zone.js:264 

    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:362 

    Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:166 

    drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:529 "**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but there is no way to extend template.

To fix this error you need to provide in `constructor` all dependencies for MultiSelect component:

`constructor(el: ElementRef, domHandler: DomHandler, renderer: Renderer, differs: IterableDiffers) {
    super(el, domHandler, renderer, differs);
}`

Comment: I had made an error, did not mention that the providers for my extended class. Added the Domhandler as the provider and it worked.