# Extending Primeng Autocomplete component inside Angular 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I am trying to extend PrimeNg Autocomplete component inside angular. I need to add events on `keyup.enter` so that I can make it behave like select by autocomplete or create new.
I copied the template html and added the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSORS` referring [Extending a PrimeNg component inside Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519015/extending-a-primeng-component-inside-angular2) and [Extending components in PrimeNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535485/extending-components-in-primeng?rq=1)

I still get the following error:

> ERROR Error: No provider for DomHandler!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9475)
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10557)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11060)
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10924)

Comment: Please correct your tags

Comment: Add Domhandler as provider

Answer (score 0):

In your decorator, add to the providers 'DomHandler'.

e.g.:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyClass),
    multi: true
  }, DomHandler],
  template: ``
})
export class MyClass {}
```